# Using seq and rep to create a sequence of 5 integers that go up by 1 on each repetition

Tags: r, sequence

I'm trying to create the vector: 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
using `rep` and `seq` functions

So far I have this:

```
rep(seq(1,5),5)
```

Which yields:

1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add the +1 incrementally.

I have tried `rep(seq(1,5),5,+1)` and `rep(seq(1,5),5, each +1` and many other variations.

Is a for loop needed?

Answer (score 5):

Using R's feature of recycling vectors:

```
1:5 + rep(0:4, each = 5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Note that `1:5` gives the same result as `seq(1,5)`.

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: Using vector recycling for this is really in the spirit of R, nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `sequence`:

```
sequence(nvec = rep(5L, 5L), from = 1:5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

*Note*: the `from` argument was introduced in R 4.0.0. From [R News 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html):

> `sequence()` [...] gains arguments [e.g. `from`] to generate more complex sequences.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a case of divide and conquer. So you basically want to build a sequence of 1-5, 2-6, 3-7, 4-8, 5-9. The pattern here being i-(i+4).

So here's a solution:

```
unlist(lapply(1:5, function(i) seq(i, i+4)))
```

You perform your sub-pattern for i = 1-5. The outcome is a list, hence you unlist it, bringing you down to a simple

```
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

*Edit:* Yes, you did need a "loop", but this demonstrates clearly that in R, many loop-operations can be performed with the `*apply` functions (`sapply`, `lapply`, `apply`, `mapply`).

In this case, we perform the *same* function on different values which is why it is easier to use `sapply`. If you have a calculation where you rely on a previous value or row, traditional loops are the way to go.

Here, your function is `seq(i, i+4)`. When it is this simple, we don't bother assigning it to a name, but have instead made a "lambda function" or "anonymous" function. The exact same result could have been achieved by:

```
sequence_1_to_4 <- function(i) {
  seq(i, i+4)
}
sequences <- lapply(1:5, sequence_1_to_4)
single_sequence <- unlist(sequences)
```

Answer (score 0):

In new R, you could do this. The `\(x)` is a shortcut for a function.

```
c(sapply(1:5, \(x) x:(x+4)))
```