# Creating an repeating but increasing sequence in R

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I want to create the sequence `1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9` if possible using only `rep` and 'seq'. So each repetition I want the repeating sequence to increase by one. This could be achieved my creating `rep(seq(1,5),5)` and then adding a vector `rep(0:4, each = 5)`.

But is there any way to do this without creating a new vector and adding it to the first one?

Comment: You don't need to create new vector. Do -  `rep(seq(1,5),5) + rep(0:4, each = 5)`

Comment: Yeah, but it is spiritually the same I think. I was more wondering if you could use either `rep` or `seq` and make them do more "advanced" patterning.

Comment: you don't need `seq`, just `(1:5) + rep(0:4, e=5)` will do

Comment: This is a pretty neat way to do it. Nice

Comment: I just posted an answer using `sequence` to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191825/r-using-seq-and-rep-to-create-a-sequence-of-5-integers-that-go-up-by-1-on-each-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer` + `seq` in one line

```
> c(outer(seq(5), seq(5) - 1, `+`))
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

or shorter code with `embed`

```
> c(embed(1:9, 5)[, 5:1])
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: The embed solution is really , really neat. Great solution!