# Create a sequence of sequences of numbers

Tags: r, math, vector, sequence, rep

I would like to make the following sequence in R, by using `rep` or any other function.

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5)
```

Basically, `c(1:5, 2:5, 3:5, 4:5, 5:5)`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `sequence`.

```r
sequence(5:1, from = 1:5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

The first argument, `nvec`, is the length of each sequence (`5:1`); the second, `from`, is the starting point for each sequence (`1:5`).

*Note*: this works only for R >= 4.0.0. From [R News 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html):

> `sequence()` [...] gains arguments [e.g. `from`] to generate more complex sequences.

Comment: @Henrik A very similar question answered some time ago using `sequence`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887135/9463489

Answer (score 8):

```
unlist(lapply(1:5, function(i) i:5))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

**Some speed tests on all answers provided**
*note the OP mentioned 10K somewhere if I recall correctly*

```
s1 <- function(n) { 
  unlist(lapply(1:n, function(i) i:n))
}

s2 <- function(n) {
  unlist(lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) seq(from = i, to = n, by = 1)))
}

s3 <- function(n) {
  vect <- 0:n
  unlist(replicate(n, vect <<- vect[-1]))
}

s4 <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(1:n, ncol = n, nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- 0
  c(t(m)[t(m != 0)])
}

s5 <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(seq.int(n), ncol = n, nrow = n)
  m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)]
}

s6 <- function(n) {
  out <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) { 
    out <- c(out, (1:n)[i:n])
  }
  out
}

library(rbenchmark)
```

**n = 5**

```
n = 5L

benchmark(
  "s1" = { s1(n) },
  "s2" = { s2(n) },
  "s3" = { s3(n) },
  "s4" = { s4(n) },
  "s5" = { s5(n) },
  "s6" = { s6(n) },
  replications = 1000,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative")
)
```

Do not get fooled by some "fast" solutions using hardly any function that takes time to be called, and differences are multiplied by 1000x replications.

```
  test replications elapsed relative
1   s1         1000    0.05      2.5
2   s2         1000    0.44     22.0
3   s3         1000    0.14      7.0
4   s4         1000    0.08      4.0
5   s5         1000    0.02      1.0
6   s6         1000    0.02      1.0
```

**n = 1000**

```
n = 1000L

benchmark(
  "s1" = { s1(n) },
  "s2" = { s2(n) },
  "s3" = { s3(n) },
  "s4" = { s4(n) },
  "s5" = { s5(n) },
  "s6" = { s6(n) },
  replications = 10,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative")
)
```

As the poster already mentioned as "not to do", we see the `for` loop becoming pretty slow compared to any other method, on `n = 1000L`

```
  test replications elapsed relative
1   s1           10    0.17    1.000
2   s2           10    0.83    4.882
3   s3           10    0.19    1.118
4   s4           10    1.50    8.824
5   s5           10    0.29    1.706
6   s6           10   28.64  168.471
```

**n = 10000**

```
n = 10000L

benchmark(
  "s1" = { s1(n) },
  "s2" = { s2(n) },
  "s3" = { s3(n) },
  "s4" = { s4(n) },
  "s5" = { s5(n) },
  # "s6" = { s6(n) },
  replications = 10,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative")
)
```

At big n's we see matrix becomes very slow compared to the other methods.
Using seq in the apply might be neater, but comes with a trade-off as calling that function n times increases processing time a lot. Although seq_len(n) is nicer than 1:n and is just run once. Interesting to see that the replicate method is the fastest.

```
  test replications elapsed relative
1   s1           10    5.44    1.915
2   s2           10    9.98    3.514
3   s3           10    2.84    1.000
4   s4           10   72.37   25.482
5   s5           10   35.78   12.599
```

Comment: Careful with this. It will misbehave if you change the first argument without remembering to change the second. For example, `unlist(lapply(1:10, function(i) i:5))` isn't right. Changing the second argument to `function(i) seq(from = i, to = 5, by = 1)` is a lot more verbose, but it's safer. The ultimate version is probably something like `output <- function(x) unlist(lapply(seq_len(x), function(i) seq(from = i, to = x, by = 1)))`.

Comment: Hi @Merijn van Tilborg! Perhaps you could include the `sequence` answer in the timings as well? Cheers

Comment: I would have if I could, but I have not the R version that supports the from argument. I expect it to be the same speed as s1 or s2 as if we look at the old sequence function it is basically a wrapper of `R: sequence
function (nvec) 
unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len))`

Comment: Indeed, but it seems like that is [no longer the case](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/seq.R#L175-L177), so the timing may actually differ.

Comment: A quick `system.time` with `sequence` and n = 10000 suggests that it is about 8-9 times faster than the `replicate` method.

Comment: This could also be shortened to `unlist(lapply(1:5, ':', 5))`.

Answer (score 5):

Your mention of `rep` reminded me of `replicate`, so here's a very stateful solution. I'm presenting this because it's short and unusual, not because it's good. This is **very** unidiomatic R.

```
vect <- 0:5
unlist(replicate(5, vect <<- vect[-1]))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

You can do it with a combination of `rep` and `lapply`, but it's basically the same as Merijn van Tilborg's answer.

Of course, the truly fearless unidomatic R user does this and refuses to elaborate further.

```
mat <- matrix(1:5, ncol = 5, nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- 0
c(t(mat)[t(mat != 0)])
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

Comment: Your matrix alternative can be slightly simplified: `m = matrix(seq.int(n), ncol = n, nrow = n)`; `m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)]` (less unidiomatic though)

Comment: @Henrik Good job. I knew that something was off when I had to call `t` twice while using `byrow=TRUE`.

Comment: I fully understand. I have got lost in the maze of `upper/lower.tri`/`byrow`/"to `t` or not to `t`" soo many times myself. Your unidiomatic contribution is much appreciated.

Comment: The indexing could be golfed with `row(m)>=col(m)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop like so:

```
out=c();for(i in 1:5){ out=c(out, (1:5)[i:5]) }
out
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

but that's not a good idea!

---

#### Why not use a loop?

Using a loop is:

- slower,
- less memory efficient, and
- harder to read and understand.

By contrast, using a vectorised function like `sequence` is the opposite (faster, more efficient, and easy to read).

---

#### Further info

From `?sequence`:

> The default method for sequence generates the sequence `seq(from[i], by = by[i], length.out = nvec[i])` for each element `i` in the parallel (and recycled) vectors `from`, `by` and `nvec`. It then returns the result of concatenating those sequences.

and about the `from` argument:

> from: each element specifies the first element of a sequence.

Also, since the vector used in the loop is not preallocated, it will require more memory, and will also be slower.