# How to create a sequence of sequences of numbers in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

<sup>Inspired by the post [How to create a sequence of sequences of numbers in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70579403/12416453).</sup>

---

Question:

I would like to make the following sequence in NumPy.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]
```

I have tried the following:

- Non-generic and hard coding using [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

  ```
  np.r_[1:6, 2:6, 3:6, 4:6, 5:6]
  # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5])
  ```
- Pure Python to generate the desired array.

  ```
  n = 5
  a = np.r_[1:n+1]
  [i for idx in range(a.shape[0]) for i in a[idx:]]
  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]
  ```
- Create a 2D array and take the upper triangle from it.

  ```
  n = 5
  a = np.r_[1:n+1]
  arr = np.tile(a, (n, 1))
  print(arr)
  # [[1 2 3 4 5]
  #  [1 2 3 4 5]
  #  [1 2 3 4 5]
  #  [1 2 3 4 5]
  #  [1 2 3 4 5]]

  o = np.triu(arr).flatten()
  # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  #        0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  #        0, 0, 3, 4, 5, # This is 1D array
  #        0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 
  #        0, 0, 0, 0, 5])

  out = o[o > 0]
  # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5])
  ```

The above solution is generic but I want to know if there's a more efficient way to do it in NumPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea but I tried running it against your python method and it seems to be faster.

```
np.concatenate([np.arange(i, n+1) for i in range(1, n+1)])
```

Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

n = 5000

t = time()
c = np.concatenate([np.arange(i, n+1) for i in range(1, n+1)])
print(time() - t)
# 0.039876699447631836

t = time()
a = np.r_[1:n+1]
b = np.array([i for idx in range(a.shape[0]) for i in a[idx:]])
print(time() - t)
# 2.0875167846679688

print(all(b == c))
# True
```

Comment: Faster than both the mentioned methods. Nice one.

Comment: I didn't expect `concat` to be so fast!. I assume that it calculates the size of the final array in advance so it can allocate all the memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

A *really* plain Python (no numpy) way is:

```
n = 5
a = [r for start in range(1, n+1) for r in range(start, n+1)]
```

This will be faster for small `n` (~150) but slower than @tangolin's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70593975/17457042) for larger n. It is still faster than the OP's "pure python" way.

A faster implementation prepares the data in advance, avoiding creating a new range each time :

```
source = np.arange(1, n+1)
d = np.concatenate([source[i: n+1] for i in range(0, n)])
```

**NOTE**

My original implementation both allocated space for the return value and prepared the data in advance, but it was not *pythonic*. I changed it to use `concatenate` after reading [@tangolin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70593975/17457042) and noticed that `concatenate` does the same.

Original implementation:

```
e = np.empty((n*(n+1)//2, ), dtype='int64')
source = np.arange(1, n+1)
for i in range(n):
    init = n * i - i*(i-1)//2
    end = n - i + init
    e[init:end] = source[i:n]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.